# Colocar "=" en un string de un parametro en la URL

Tags: php, email

Quiero compartir una url por correo cuando se pulse un botón. Para eso tengo este link:

```
$url = www.wikipedia.com?tema=1; //Solo es de ejemplo la url
<a href="mailto:?subject=Visitenos!&body=<?php echo $url; ?>" >Correo</a>
```

La variable $url tiene parametros y cuando le doy para compartir en el correo me aparece hasta tema, es decir el =1 no se muestra. Como haria para que ese parametro se envie como parte de la url

Comment: Ya viste que no sea el hecho que faltan las comillas de la variable **$url**?? `$url = 'www.wikipedia.com?tema=1';` Yo la probé y me funciona bien. (enviándolo a un archivo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para asegurarte de que el parámetro tema se incluya correctamente en la URL, puedes utilizar la función urlencode() de PHP para codificar el valor de $url y luego concatenar el parámetro tema a la URL. Aquí tienes una solución:

```
<?php
$url = "www.wikipedia.com?tema=1"; // Solo es un ejemplo de URL
$encodedUrl = urlencode($url . '&tema=1');

$mailtoLink = 'mailto:?subject=Visitenos!&body=' . $encodedUrl;
?>

<a href="<?php echo $mailtoLink; ?>">Correo</a>
```

En este código, utilizamos la función urlencode() para codificar la URL completa, incluyendo el parámetro tema. Tras ello concatenamos el parámetro tema a la URL codificada y luego construimos el enlace de correo electrónico (mailto) concatenando el asunto y el cuerpo del correo electrónico, que ahora incluye la URL completa y codificada con el parámetro tema.

Al hacer clic en el enlace "Correo", ahora debería abrirse el cliente de correo electrónico con la URL completa, incluyendo el parámetro tema.

Espero que esta explicación te haya sido útil

Comment: Me funciono perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Esto me funciona, estoy usando chrome y el correo de windows

```
<?php
$url = "www.wikipedia.com?tema=1"; //Solo es de ejemplo la url
?>
<a href="mailto:?subject=Visitenos!&body=<?php echo $url; ?>">Correo</a>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Igual te recomendaría usar [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php) para evitar problemas

```
<?php
$url = "www.wikipedia.com?tema=1"; //Solo es de ejemplo la url
?>
<a href="mailto:?subject=Visitenos!&body=<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>">Correo</a>
```